# Pyspark - RollUp with fixed column

Tags: pyspark

I have a spark dataframe with three columns: *a*, *b*, *c*. I want to run a rollup for each value in *a*. The output would be the same that for running:

```
df.rollup('a','b','c')
```

But without a column with `a=Null, b=Null, c=Null`. I don't want to compute this row because the df is partitioned by *a* and it is very expensive. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with:

`df.rollup('a', 'b', 'c').where(F.col('a').isNotNull() | F.col('b').isNotNull() | F.col('c').isNotNull())`

This doesn't compute the total of the three levels.